# מוחין דגדלות and מוחין דקטנות — explained?

Tags: zohar

I’m looking for sources on good authority, explaining well the concept of מוחין דגדלות and מוחין דקטנות.

Which is mentioned (but not limited to with regards to this question) in [Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan’s](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/92034/zohar-quote-about-kiss) book on page 8.

[image]

Comment: Do they need to be in English? That would seriously limit what you have access to.

Comment: No, Not at all!

Comment: The purpose of comments that seek clarification is always that the post's author may edit such clarification into the post, and never that he may add further comments. Comments are ephemeral by design and may disappear at any time.

Answer (score 1):

I"m not sure if this what you are looking for. The Michtav M'Eliyahu Vol. 5 pg יח has a short piece on this. [I"m not sure if you have the text so here's part of it.]

ויש שמצב נקודת הבחירה משתנה גם מפאת השפעות מלמעלה, בזמן שהוא מקבל מלמעלה את השפע הנקרא מוחין דגדלות, נקודת בחירתו עולה. ובהעדר הגדלות, והוא מקבל במקומה מוחין דקטנות, נקודת בחירתו יורדת. בזמן מוחין דגדלות, הוא מרגיש קירבה אל הקב"ה, וגם היכולת להתפלל יותר בכוונה, ללמוד יותר בחשק, וכו'. ובזמן מוחין דקטנות, הכל להיפך. יש לדעת, שהמצב של מוחין דגדלות אינו משלנו, אלא סייעתא דשמיא היא. מדרגתנו האמתית היא קרוב יותר לצד מוחין דקטנות, עבודתנו היא איפוא להאיר בשעת הגדלות לתוך הקטנות שבעומק הלב, ולעשות בה רושם, עד שבהסתלק אור 
 הגדלות, נמצא שנתעלה הקטנות על ידי הרושם ההוא....מכתב מאליהו חלק ה' דף יח

Comment: There’s a fifth volume...? I only have 4..

Comment: I also have only 4 volumes, but I was quoting this from אספקלריא ל pg 29.

Comment: What is that? @user17260

Comment: אספקלריא is a set of ספרים which are about מחשבה set up by topic  in alphabetic order. Printed in the 1990's, and found on Otzar Hachochma.